# A custom field that can search through many other related post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

It's been half a decade since I tried to make a wordpress site, and in the past I would use Advance Custom Fields to solve a very specific problem I'm about to ask. I want to see if there's a newer and conventional approach before I default to using ACF.  Here's what I want to achieve:

In the CMS, I want to setup 2 custom post types: Concerts and Artists.   I could have potentially thousands of artists in my database.  When I create a new concert record, I want to be able to assign multiple artists to a concert.  I don't want the CMS to use a normal `<select>` or a lot of `<input type="checkbox" name="artist_id[]"/>` because it would be a bad user experience to try to find just a few artists within a list of thousands.  Ideally, I want to be able to search for artist by keyword search and using some AJAX, it shows the most relevant results for me to click on.

Does wordpress have that capability right out of hte box?  Or do I need to code my own plugin to do this?  Or is ACF still the most popular way to addressing this situation?